# Ignore/Exclude a client application

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Is there a way to configure Spring Boot Admin server to ignore specific clients based on their name.

The clients are registering with `spring-boot-admin-client`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case? For an instance to register via `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` you have to explicitly configure the URL of the Spring Boot Admin server (`spring.boot.admin.client.url`). If you don't want your instance to register, can't you just leave the URL property unset? Or even better, don't add `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` as a dependency?